# Private class member vs. Method with return type

Tags: c#

I've recently been tinkering around with C# and have come across a problem:

I have four classes:

- Program: with the Main method.
- Game: The place where everything happens.
- Entity: basic entity class.
- Player: derived from entity

(Both Entity and Player are within the Game class)

Now, my question is, which is is better:

1. To make a private object of Player in my Game class and access said object with some public methods, or...
2. To make some public methods and return a new Player object from those to be accessed throughout the class?

This might be badly explained, so here's an example:

To 1:

```
namespace Test
{
    class Game
    {
        public Game()
        {
            createChar();
        }
        private Player player;

        public class Entity
        {
            public string type;
        }
        public class Player : Entity
        {
            public string name;
        }

        private void createChar()
        {
            player = new Player();

            Console.WriteLine("What type of being is your character?");
            player.type = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Name your character.");
            player.name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        public void run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your character's name is:");
            Console.WriteLine(player.name);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Game game = new Game();
            game.run();
        }
    }
}
```

To 2:

```
namespace Test
{
    class Game
    {
        public class Entity
        {
            public string type;
        }
        public class Player : Entity
        {
            public string name;
        }

        public Player createChar()
        {
            Player player = new Player();

            Console.WriteLine("What type of being is your character?");
            player.type = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Name your character.");
            player.name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            return player;
        }

        public void run(Player player)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your character's name is:");
            Console.WriteLine(player.name);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Game game = new Game();
            Game.Player player = game.createChar();
            game.run(player);
        }
    }
}
```

This question isn't supposed to be open ended and I apologize if it seems to be, but to make my question a little more specific, here is a list of all the questions I have regarding this code:

1. Which program is better 1. or 2.?
2. Which program is more scalable?
3. Is there an even better way to write the program?
4. Am I missing any questions that should probably be asked?

Also, please ignore the emptiness of the classes Entity and Player.

Comment: go with 2 - make `class Game` into a static class and extract `Player` out of it (why nest those?)

Comment: Take a look at [Recommendations on Nested Classes in Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9f3ty7f(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a code review.

Comment: Thanks Carsten, that pretty much answered my question.

Comment: Sorry bradley, I didn't intend for that.

Comment: (follow up to @BradleyDotNET) It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: This is like asking "Buy an Audi or BMW"... In the limited example you provided, both are working. The difference comes into play when having a bigger application, and you want to restrict usage of classes that do not make sence *out of their scope*. (Assume a dedicated Class `Name` which has different implementations depending on the outer Object. You don't want to confuse Animal-Names with Human Names -> private class.)

Comment: Can someone tell me why the classes Player and Entity shouldn't be nested? Because they seem pretty relevant to the Game class.

Comment: Your `Entity` and `Player` classes don't have any reason to be nested inside of your `Game` class. Your `Entity` class likely should be `abstract`, but it's hard to tell given your minimal example. Those public fields likely should be encapsulated as properties. The question of whether or not you should pass an instance of `Player` to to `run` or have it be an instance member of `Game` is answered by whether or not you need `Game` to know about the player instance outside of that method (likely, it does). "Scalable" isn't even close a concern with this snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option two sounds better because less code is required in the Game class (you don't need methods for each piece of data you want user classes of Game to be able to access about a Player) and it's more flexible (changes to the Player class don't need to have methods altered in the Game class).

The only reason I can see to go with option 1 would be if you have another class that accesses data about a Player object directly (so without going through the Game class) and that data really, really should not be accessed by classes that use the Game class to access Player data, therefore justifying having methods within Game that only allows user classes of Game to access certain data from Player.